# C++ operator overloading error C2804 too many parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create an operator overloading function to add 2 vectors. Declaration goes like this:

```
class VecOperations
{
public:
    std::vector<double> operator + (const std::vector<double> &, const std::vector<double> &);
};
```

But there is error `binary operator + has too many parameters`. Any idea why this is so? I want to add 2 vectors with operator overloading.

Edit:
After taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/9329547

> ```
> class X {
>   X& operator+=(const X& rhs)
>   {
>     // actual addition of rhs to *this
>     return *this;
>   }
> };
> inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)
> {
>   lhs += rhs;
>   return lhs;
> }
> ```

I am confused as in my question I am not passing class instance to the operator overloaded function, but passing 2 vectors. Can someone explain what is proper way to declare the function?

Comment: The non-static member functions have `this` as one argument and need only one to be binary operators.

Comment: You probably want a namespace instead of class here.

Comment: There are two proper ways, your edit shows the two alternatives.